# Translation of "symbolisme appuyé"

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire

I'm currently reading through and attempting to translate an article about a film in which the phrase "symbolisme appuyé" is used. The full phrase is "et oeuvre au symbolisme appuyé," so I believe it refers to a style of filmmaking that I'm unfamiliar with the French translation of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Appuyé*, used figuratively, means that something is done or expressed with insistence (it can even be slightly negative , meaning it does it too much).

Therefore, *une oeuvre au symbolisme appuyé* means "a work of art that resorts heavily to symbolism, in a very visible way*.

It is not specific to filmmaking or even to symbolism. You could say for instance:

> Il a lancé un regard appuyé.
>
> Il fait souvent des plaisanteries appuyées sur les femmes.
>
> Il a rendu un hommage appuyé à son prédecesseur.